# How to close an android app if webview is not able to load a webpage

Tags: android, webview

Basically my android app loads a link on a webview which i do not want to be displayed if there is no internet connection, so i want to either force close the app or hide the link from the user. Below  is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mainWebView.loadUrl("my link which should not be displayed to user");
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}`enter code here`
```

i have tried connection manager, finish(),System.out.exit(0) and other functions, but it does not kill the app. So any help would be great.

Comment: where did you put `finish()`?

Comment: i had put a condition before mainWebView.loadUrl("my link which should not be displayed to user"); then excute finish(), it didnot work

Comment: you have to call `finish` in `WebViewClient`'s `onReceivedError` method. did you do that?

Comment: no, have not tried that, and i do not know how can it be done, can you show it  ?

Comment: see my answer. there's sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, 
             String description, String failingUrl) {
        AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code hides the url, its perfect, thanks, but please see my answer as it gives much better feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer just type the code

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, 
    String description, String failingUrl) {
      mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

    }
});`
```

`
This will take care of hiding the url from the user